# Redo Backup CD odd green graphics on boot

Tags: linux, backup

I’ve put redo back up onto CD whenever I boot into it, I get green graphics

[image]

Instead of the CD contents

I'm using NVIDIA 1080 Ti and i7 CPU

I’ve tried using lower resolution screen, using older video cables DVI but nothing seems to make scrap of difference

Comment: I never worked with Redo, though I know artifacts like this from CloneZilla or Debian disks - they have a switch in the first menu that is called something along `failsafeX`. As Redo is based on Ubuntu (and therefore Debian), if they did not exclude that boot menu and if you get that far, you could try this flag and report back if that helped.

Comment: @flolilolilo I found it works most of the time on a lower resolution or using onboard Intel Graphics instead of NVIDIA